# Ubuntu 20.04 on Vmware freezes when connected to internet

Tags: 20.04, freeze

I have a long existing problem. I'm running a VMware ESX server (6.5) with multiple Ubuntu servers on it. Two of the servers host a website (one public website, other web base mail client). Both servers have an IPv4 and IPv6 address.

These are working fine most of the time. Now and then there are periods where one or both servers freeze. CPU usage goes to 100% and I cannot login to the servers anymore. Not even via the VMware direct console. The only way to revive these systems is to do a hard reboot.

The server(s) run for a couple of minutes. This goes on for hours, sometimes a day then the servers suddenly stop freezing and run without problems for weeks. The strange thing is that when I block the servers from internet (remove port forwarding) the freezing stops. The other strange thing is that all the other Ubuntu servers do not have this freezing problem. They are all installed the same way.

In the log I was able to find the following consistent entry:

```
Apr 21 14:30:39 helios kernel: [  124.446850] [UFW BLOCK] IN=ens160 OUT= MAC=00:0c:29:f3:7b:e8:98:9b:cb:b2:87:d9:08:00 SRC=62.204.66.10 DST=10.0.0.65 LEN=40 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=58 ID=0 DF PROTO=TCP SPT=22016 DPT=443 WINDOW=0 RES=0x00 RST URGP=0
^@^^@^@^@^@^@^@ 
^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^
[...]

Apr 21 14:36:00 helios systemd-sysctl[497]: Not setting net/ipv4/conf/all/promote_secondaries (explicit setting exists).
Apr 21 14:36:00 helios systemd-sysctl[497]: Not setting net/ipv4/conf/default/promote_secondaries (explicit setting exists).
Apr 21 14:36:00 helios systemd[1]: Starting Flush Journal to Persistent Storage...
```

The moment the strange characters are written, the server hangs. I have the idea it has to do with the UFW firewall. When I disable the firewall the freezing is less frequent. I want to keep the UFW firewall running as a safeguard. I only enable HTTP(S) and SSH in UFW. SSH is not forwarded on the router(duh).

**Update:** it is probably not the UFW firewall, as the system still keeps freezing when UFW is disabled.

I'm struggling with this for years now. The problem existed on Ubuntu 18.04 and keeps happening on Ubuntu 20.04. In that time I replaced the complete hardware (was outdated) and upgraded VMware from 5 to 6.5. So it is not hardware or ESX related.

Could this be a denial of service attack of some kind? And if so, can I secure my server for this?

Apache 2 is installed and I enabled mod security and mod evasive to stop all kinds of attacks. I have secured the server as best as I can.